# Custom headers HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#

How to send a header containing "ffa" only;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
    // Assign the response object of 'HttpWebRequest' to a 'HttpWebResponse' variable.
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    request.Headers.Clear();
    request.Headers.Add("ffa", null);// request.Headers.Add("ffa", null) not appropriate.


    Console.WriteLine("\nThe HttpHeaders are \n\n\tName\t\tValue\n{0}", request.Headers);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In header need send only "ffa" string, nothing else. Sring "ffa:" not appropriate.

Comment: Have you tried string.Empty instead of NULL?

Comment: From https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2: "Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
   by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
   optional trailing whitespace." So what you're asking for simply isn't HTTP.  I suggest you revisit your requirements.